# Send HTTP request and wait for 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, request

i was wondering  how can i send a HTTP request to a website and keep the connection live for 30 seconds and then kill it.
Is it possible with PHP or Javascript?

For example:
1. Script sends a request to stackoverflow
2. The connection will be kept alive for 30 seconds
3. After expiring the connection will be closed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: Not sure, my friend asked me and i am really curious how can this be done.

Comment: Use `fsockopen()` to open the connection, send the HTTP request with `fputs(), and then sleep for 30 seconds before closing the connection.

Comment: @Iskren If you want to scrape the html of a page? Why do you care how long the request takes? If you're pulling the HTML, you have no way to control how long the request (webpage you're pulling from) takes.

Comment: Not sure, i just want to keep the connection alive for some amount of time.

Comment: *I want to keep the connection alive, but i don't know why* Seems legit

Answer (score 1):

Open the connection manually using `fsockopen()` so you can control the timing of sending the request and closing the connection.

```
$conn = fsockopen("stackoverflow.com", 80);
$request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
    "Host: stackoverflow.com\r\n" + 
    "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
fputs($conn, $request);
$response = fgets($conn);
sleep(30);
close($conn);
```

`Connection: keep-alive` tells the server to keep the connection open until the client closes it (this is actually the default in HTTP/1.1, but no harm in sending it explicitly).

However, most webservers have an inactivity timeout that will close connections that are idle. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) this defaults to 15 seconds in Apache httpd 1.3 and 2.0, and 5 seconds in httpd 2.2. So it's likely that the above code won't be effective. You would have to keep sending new requests every couple of seconds to keep the server from closing the connection.